# Filesystem for NOR flash

Tags: filesystems

I have a flash device with 6114 blocks of 1024 bytes data. I have the two following functions to access the flash:

```
long WriteData (long StartBlock, long Count, void *ptr)
long ReadData  (long StartBlock, long Count, void *ptr)
```

Is there some open source code to simulate a filesystem on top of these two functions?

Thanks!

Comment: Creating a simple FAT-like system is very easy, especially if you're okay with a flat structure (no directories). Other than that there are a few filesystems designed for FLASH memory, and *many* other filesystems, all open source in both design and implementation (though the implementations are mostly for existing kernels that might not be compatible with whatever kernel you're using). Also see if the kernel you're using (if any) doesn't already support one or more filesystems.

Comment: I use these functions on a Windows PC. These is my interface (function exported from a dll) to a custom board. So no kernel or something else. I know its not this difficult but any work I can avoid is good work...

Comment: did you take a look at littlefs? https://github.com/littlefs-project/littlefs